# python functools.partial of which function

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import functools
import random
import inspect 

def myfirst(a, b):
    return a + b

def mysecond(c, d):
    return c - d

def returnAPartial():  
    myrand = random.randrange(0,2)
    if myrand == 1:
        return functools.partial(myfirst, 1)
    else:
        return functools.partial(mysecond, 2)
```

I load it into python interactive and run:

```
myfunc = returnAPartial()
```

I want to check (programmatically) if myfunc is a partial application of the myfirst or mysecond function (not by calculating, the example is a bit contrived) So far I have used [inspect.getmembers()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) but I couldn't find a suitable attribute to check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`partial` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects) have a `func` attribute, which is what you want:

```
 myfunc = returnAPartial()
 print myfunc.func # <function mysecond at 0x10c918488>
```

Comment: +1, I made the presumption it didn't exist as the asker mentioned checking. Clearly not too carefully ;)

Comment: thanks, my bad, I missed this item in the attribute list I got when running inspect.getmembers(myfunc)

Answer (score 1):

Internal `help` command can give you some hints:

```
>import _functools
>help(_functools.partial)
...
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |
 |  __dict__
 |
 |  args
 |      tuple of arguments to future partial calls
 |
 |  func
 |      function object to use in future partial calls
 |
 |  keywords
 |      dictionary of keyword arguments to future partial calls
 |
```

Comment: thanks this is helpful, I have been defaulting to looking online for documentation without realizing how much that is available in the command line interpreter.